# rename file that user uploads javascript

Tags: javascript, file, input

I have the following html on a form:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadField" />
```

When users click on the browse button they can select any file but I want to rename the file using the value of another field on the form

I have a submit button. Can I do it here?

Comment: rename the file after it uploads on the server?

Comment: you cannot deal with file to be uploaded with js what so ever

Comment: You need to do it at the server level.

Comment: if u are using php for the server side language u want somthing like http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php functions

Answer (score 14):

> Can I do it here?

No, for security reasons you have no control of this on the client. You can rename the file on the server when it gets uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but if anyone is still struggling with similar problem, please try to use [append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) or [set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) method of the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons you cannot do such thing i.e. manipulate multipart file or file to be uploaded do that on server