# jQuery File Upload, only single image and rename before uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am using the [JQuery File Upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html).

I want to limit upload to one image, and replace if another image is selected, and rename before uploading to the server.My html code

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]"> 
</span>
```

I tried to make few changes in file

```
jquery.fileupload.js
```

but no success.

Comment: I got the problem solve with [this link](http://coursesweb.net/ajax/upload-images) . Its usefull for this kind of problem.
Shared it because of vote up from someone who might need this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I realize this was asked a long time ago, but the other response is an incomplete answer when other tools like DropzoneJS have a way to alter the filename before it is sent to the server.  After scouring the source code, it turns out that jQuery File Upload also has the ability.

In a jQuery File Upload `submit` event callback OR at any time before calling `data.submit()`, alter the `files` array and set `uploadName`.  For example:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    submit: function(e, data) {
        data.files[0].uploadName = 'mynewfilename.jpg';
    }
});
```

While the `name` property on a browser-controlled `File` object is read-only, that doesn't stop new properties from being defined.  jQuery File Upload sends `uploadName` if it exists, otherwise it falls back to `name`.

Of course, nothing here excludes server-side responsibilities to validate the incoming data, but it does show that it is possible to change the filename that jQuery File Upload sends to the server.

Comment: I recently released a complete, reusable user interface for jQuery File Upload that makes it easy to allow the user to modify filenames:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/jquery-fancyfileuploader

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons client side javascripts do not have control of this. You can rename the file on the server when it gets uploaded.

Similar question and answer ware given here [rename file that user uploads javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569620/rename-file-that-user-uploads-javascript)

Best practice is to rename files on server-side, e.g. in the PHP script

you can limit your files with maxNumberOfFiles option

```
$('#fileuploadbasic').fileupload({
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1
});
```

Comment: `Filenames can only be changed on server-side, e.g. in the PHP script` - your statement is too conclusive to be true.